# Remove all nested documents of a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to remove all of the nested documents not just one.

here is the code:

```
        //find and remove all of the embedded workorder units
    db.workorders.find({units: { $ne: null } }, function(err, wos) {

      console.log(wos);
      console.log("removing the embedded workorder units");
      _.each(wos, function(wo) {

        wo.units.remove();
      });

      setTimeout(function() { next() }, 2000);

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
        //find and remove all of the embedded workorder units
    db.workorders.update({}, { $set: { units: [] } }, { multi: true }, function(err) {

      console.log("removing the embedded workorder units");

      next();

    });
```

Comment: Do you want to have an empty array left?  If you just want to remove the field you can use {$unset:{units:1}}